# Print setProperty values in java

Tags: java

I am novice in Java and need to put debugs in a file to resolve a issue. Can someone help me to print the values of all the properties in prop.setProperty. Below is the code

```
 public static Properties loadPropFromObj(DatabaseConfigInfo dbConfig) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    System.out.println("INSIDE loadPropFromObj");
    prop.setProperty("dataSourceName" , dbConfig.getDataSourceName() );
    prop.setProperty("DatabaseServerUrl" , dbConfig.getDbServerURL());
    prop.setProperty("DatabaseDriverName" , dbConfig.getDbDriverName());
    prop.setProperty("DatabaseServerName" , dbConfig.getDbServerName());
    prop.setProperty("DatabaseName" , dbConfig.getDbName());
    prop.setProperty("DatabaseUserName" , dbConfig.getDbUserName());
    prop.setProperty("DatabasePassword" ,       dbConfig.getDbPassword().toString());
    prop.setProperty("CrmDataSource" , dbConfig.getCrmDataSource());
    prop.setProperty("InterfaceDataSource" ,         dbConfig.getInterfaceDataSource());
    prop.setProperty("ProviderURL" , dbConfig.getProviderURL());
    prop.setProperty("ContextFactory" , dbConfig.getContextFactory());
    prop.setProperty("DatabaseMaxConnections" ,         dbConfig.getDbMaxConnections());
    prop.setProperty("DatabaseExpirationTime" , dbConfig.getDbExpiryTime());
    prop.setProperty("DatabaseRecycleTime" , dbConfig.getDbRecycleTime());
    return prop;
```

I want to get the values of dataSourceName, DatabaseServerUrl etc.

Comment: System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dataSourceName"));

Comment: When you have setXXX you have also getXXX  (getter/setter) setXXX(key, value) and getXXX(key) return value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values of the entered properties using the getProperty(name)
In your case if you want to print this data in the console that would be:

```
System.out.print(prop.getProperty("dataSourceName"));
System.out.println(prop.getProperty("DatabaseServerUrl"));
```

In case though you want to print all of them you can just loop over the set and print all of them at once.

```
prop.entrySet().forEach(a->System.out.print(a.getValue()));
```

Comment: Of course, an easier way to print them all is `System.out.println(prop);`.

Comment: @VGR didnt think that would work to be honest and didnt try it.

Answer (score 0):

We can retrieve the properties values by using **getProperty** method

```
prop.getProperty("dataSourceName");
```